# Getting products from selected category and all child categories using mySQL

Tags: mysql

First time I couldn't find the answer on here, so here goes nothing!

I have the following tables:

**dataProducts**

- productID
- productName

**dataProductCategories**

- productID
- categoryID

**dataCategories**

- categoryID
- categoryName
- parentID

Each product can belong to multiple categories so I'm using dataProductCategories to connect products to each selected category.

In dataCategories I store the categories and if the category is a child I put the categoryID for the parent in the parentID column.

What I want to get is all categories from the selected category + all (if any) child categories.

So if there's a category called Clothes and another category named Pants that has the categoryID for "Clothes" as parentID. The category "Pants" will be a child to "Clothes". Let's say I also have a category named "Sweaters", also under "Clothes".

So if I select the "Clothes" category, I want all the products that are listed under "Clothes", "Pants" and "Sweaters". Been trying to solve it for, what feels like ages now :/

I managed to get the data I want using the SQL below, but it's slow as f**k.

```
SELECT datacategories.categoryid, 
       datacategories.categoryname, 
       dataproducts.productname, 
       dataproducts.productid 
FROM   datacategories 
       JOIN dataproductcategories 
         ON datacategories.categoryid = dataproductcategories.categoryid 
       JOIN dataproducts 
         ON dataproducts.productid = dataproductcategories.productid 
WHERE  dataproducts.instock <> 0 
       AND dataproducts.instock > dataproducts.lockedstock 
       AND dataproducts.isconfig = 0 
       AND dataproducts.status = 1 
       AND dataproducts.dummy = 0 
       AND dataproducts.markeddeleted = 0 
       AND dataproducts.accountid = '88' 
       AND dataproductcategories.categoryid IN (SELECT categoryid 
                                                FROM   datacategories 
                                                WHERE  categoryid = '22828' 
                                                UNION 
                                                SELECT d.categoryid 
                                                FROM   datacategories c 
                                                       INNER JOIN datacategories 
                                                                  d 
                                                               ON c.categoryid = 
                                                                  d.parentid 
                                                WHERE  c.categoryid = '22828' 
                                                        OR c.parentid = '22828') 
GROUP  BY dataproducts.productid 
ORDER  BY dataproducts.productid DESC 
LIMIT  101 offset 0
```

Comment: Instead of `Each category can belong to multiple categories so I'm using dataProductCategories`, did you mean to say `Each _product_ can belong to multiple categories so I'm using dataProductCategories`?

Comment: If one day you'll have a child of a child then your solution will never work. Instead I would recommend using the "left right" approach as seen in this picture 
https://i2.sitepoint.com/graphics/sitepoint_numbering.gif
as this speeds up the query

Comment: `Error` change this line `union select d.categoryID` to `union select c.categoryID`

Comment: @ChristianBaumann That is correct! I have edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: @SélimAchour Ok, I will try to make sense of the picture that you posted and try to modify my query. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Ashok That change makes the query return zero results. The query that I posted above is working for me, but it's way to slow.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7dcc1/1  can you insert demo data??

Comment: You can use a closure table which will hold all the possible combinations between a parent and its direct and indirect descendants.https://awesomeopensource.com/project/developerworks/hierarchy-data-closure-table